# How to get RadioNodeList value in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to get the value of a group of radio buttons in a form. I'm using the code

```js
this.type = form['template-type'].value;
```

and this works in Chrome and Firefox. However, when I run it in IE 11, it returns `undefined`.

I've resorted to the following jQuery code to get the value:

```js
$(form['template-type']).filter(':checked').val()
```

This code works fine. My question is this: does a native method to get the RadioNodeList value exist in IE11? The MDN article mentions that IE implements the RadioNodeList API, and I can't find any posts about it not working on Google.

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled upon the same issue. It seems that IE11 returns a `HtmlCollection` instead of `RadioNodeList`, no matter how you select the radio buttons.

Here's a vanilla JS way to get the value of a group of radio buttons. They don't need to be in a form:

```
document.querySelector('input[name=radioname]:checked').value
```